# Videos look strange on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: video

I've recently installed ubuntu 12.04 to replace Windows XP on my dad's computer, as he kept having trouble with an automatic update memory leak problem that I simply could not solve. ubuntu works great for his needs, except he has a lot of video files of old tv shows that he watches. I noticed that the color looks really off on the videos on ubuntu, almost as if its way too saturated. I tried downloading VLC and it still looks the same.

The video hardware is an Intel Integrated chipset which I understand has drivers built into ubuntu. Photos, desktop backgrounds, websites, etc all look normal. It is just the videos that look strange. (avi files played from an external drive, the same files he played on Windows).

Is there something else I should be trying or some video processing setting I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

.AVI, .MKV, etc. are just a "container file formats" - the audio and video streams inside them could be encoded in any one of a number of compression formats.

When you play one of these files in VLC and press Ctrl+J a Media Information window will open on the Codec tab. Quite possibly the Video Codec used in these files is one that is not well supported by the "Free" driver pack. i.e.: You may need to install one of the alternative Codecs from one of the "Non-Free" driver packs.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the latest codecs are installed, in the case of these videos it's xvid. Is it possible the latest ubuntu codec available simply isn't up to par with what's available on windows?